# Protecting an internal clevage site from restriction enzyme while cloning

Tags: cloning, restriction-enzymes

2 restriction enzymes used to generate cohesive ends in a vector and foreign DNA(gene of interest you want to clone) also cuts the foreign DNA at an internal site. What are ways to overcome this?

Comment: What have you tried? Or is this a homework question?

Comment: I have tried protecting using DAM nethylases, but thaf gave a ladder of bands on gel electrophoresis analysis. So I am wondering how to solve this

Comment: Does your protocol use PCR and does your vector have a MCS?